# pagination of multi dimensional array

Tags: php, pagination

A sample result from the API is formatted as follows. "Limit" can be set up to 500. I've tried various pagination classes to parse the results but am unsuccessful in my attempts. They provide the option ["page"] => int(x) which they say makes it easy to paginate. Easy for code gods maybe, not me. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$var = array(7) { 
      ["errors"]=> array(0) { } 
      ["warnings"]=> array(1) { 
        [0]=> array(2) { 
          ["code"]=> string(26) "api_class_update_available" 
          ["msg"]=> string(58) "The Api class is now available in version 1.6" 
        } 
      } 
      ["data"]=> array(4) { 
        [0]=> array(3) { 
          ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
          ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword1"  
          ["price"]=> string(5) "23.99" 
        } 
        [1]=> array(3) { 
          ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
          ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword2"  
          ["price"]=> string(5) "19.99" 
        }  
        [2]=> array(3) { 
          ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
          ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword3"  
          ["price"]=> string(5) "29.99" 
        } 
        [3]=> array(3) { 
          ["url"]=> string(7) "http://" 
         ["keyword"]=> string(7) "keyword4"  
          ["price"]=> string(5) "9.99" 
        } 
      }
      ["countryCode"] => string(2) "US" 
      ["page"] => int(1) 
      ["limit"]=> int(4) 
    }
```

Comment: 'A sample result from the API ' what api?

Comment: Perhaps I'm jut not understanding.... but I don't know exactly what you're asking...

Comment: Webnet - How can I paginate an array that is structured like the code I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit incoherent, but I'll attempt to answer it.  Sounds like you just need to implement some basic pagination.  Here's a few links.

http://google.com/search?q=php+pagination

http://forums.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=99545&p=537019#p537019

Instead of database queries, you'll be using [array_slice()](http://php.net/array-slice).  Same concept though.

Comment: Thanks Jonah - my understanding is that a pagination class is coded to perform the array_slice, which it appears to do, but on the first level, array(7), not on the ["data"] array.

Comment: Then give `["data"]` to the class.

Comment: Thanks Jonah! I was able to get the pagination with using $var["data"]. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Most pagination algorithms operate under the assumption that size of the entire data set is known. In this particular example, that does not appear to be the case, so "out of the box" pagination algos might not help you.

It seems the API you're working with will gladly let you fetch pages of data by any arbitrary page number, even if there's no data at that page number (i.e., the `data` key will be an empty array).

So - what do do here then?  You have a few options

1. Only display "previous" and "next" pagination links and only fetch new data from the API when the user requests a new page of data.  The kicker here will be this: you'll have to pre-fetch and count the data in the "next" page every time to ensure that there actually *is* a next page (unless the number of records of the currently fetched page is fewer than the limit)
2. Pre-fetch *ALL* the data (in a similar process to #1 only you do it all automatically and not via user click) and chunk/paginate it yourself.  The problem with this approach is you've now taken on the burden of storing the dataset between requests, which could be quite large.  It also could involve a significant amount of API overhead on the initial page load (ignoring optimization afforded by caching)

In short: you've got some work to do.